# How do I run a .bat file from CMake?

Tags: batch-file, cmake

How do I run a .bat file from CMake in a pre-link or a post-build event?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `add_custom_command`, e.g.

```
if(WIN32)
  add_custom_command(TARGET <Your target>
                       POST_BUILD
                       COMMAND cmd //C <path to .bat file> <ARGS> )

endif()
```

For full details about `add_custom_command` run

```
cmake --help-command add_custom_command
```

Answer (score 6):

The following also works. In case you read or create a file inside the bat script don't forget to specify the exact path inside the bat script.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
    myCustomTarget
    COMMAND cmd /c E:/Myfiles/mytxt.bat
)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(myTarget myCustomTarget)
```

myTarget will be executed after myCustomTarget.

Comment: The /c is important. For those who missed it like I did.