# How to copy OpenCV DLL files into cmake debug/release folder?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, cmake

I need to copy

> C:\opencv-3.4.0.-opencl\bin\Debug\*.dll =>
>   myproj\build\bin\Debug\*.dll

and also

> C:\opencv-3.4.0.-opencl\bin\Release\*.dll =>
>   myproj\build\bin\Release\*.dll

I'd like to do it in one command for Build/Release if possible.

Comment: Thanx, missprint fixed.

Comment: I guess a post-build custom command ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html)) is one way to go.

Comment: If the goal is to be able to debug without having to manually copy the libs, I took a slightly different approach. I have a function that calls `CONFIGURE_FILE` to generate `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.vcxproj.user` that  sets up debugging properties, such as command arguments, working directory and environment. For environment, it prepends the location of the DLLs to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: What is wrong with approaches from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672739/3440745) to the question which is suggested as duplicate?

Comment: I´d recommend setting dll-location in PATH-command locally. While OpenCV-dlls are small in size, many are not, and one typically has dozens of myprojs, that employ the same dlls.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy files on a post-build command. A step through tutorial can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files).

The basic concept is that you can use batch file commands, as a post-build step in Visual Studio to do basically anything you want as you build.

A further tutorial can be found [here](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/using-build-events-in-visual-studio-to.html)

**For CMAKE**

The easiest way is to follow the advice above but instead of putting it in the post-build options in VS just add a [custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383021/how-to-run-a-bat-file-from-cmake)

Comment: IMHO the question is about using CMake to configure this automagically, rather than having to click through the MSVS GUI every time you generate a new solution. Nothing in your answer, or the tutorials you link to addresses this.

Comment: That's true, I say the VisualC++ tag and assumed visual studio. Ill add a cmake solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CPack` to handle multiple configuration at one go. See an example in the following tutorial

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html#packaging-debug-and-release-step-12

> By default, CMake’s model is that a build directory only contains a
> single configuration, be it Debug, Release, MinSizeRel, or
> RelWithDebInfo. It is possible, however, to setup CPack to bundle
> multiple build directories and construct a package that contains
> multiple configurations of the same project.

Then you will need to use either of the following method for each configuration to copy the files you need

configure_file
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html

or

add_custom_command

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

Here is an example from reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/cmake/comments/gmewhu/copy_one_file_in_src_directory_to_build_directory/

```
# Copy <filename> to build directory
set(copy_source_dir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/<path>")
set(copy_dest_dir "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Build/<path>/$<CONFIG>")
set(copy_file_name "<filename>")
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${copy_dest_dir}
)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${copy_source_dir}/${copy_file_name}" "${copy_dest_dir}/${copy_file_name}"
    COMMENT "Copying ${copy_file_name} to build directory"
)
```